# Problem running script after build in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I've read [this excellent tutorial](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/11/09/Part-14-Execute-a-PowerShell-script.aspx) but somehow this doesn't work well for me. I can't figure out how to specify the path to my script properly when it's in a subdirectory in my source control. What is the right input to specify for the script name/location when queuing the build?

Does the `ConvertWorkspaceItem` activity work on directories also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use an absolute path but rather give the relative path to the mapped build source control root. You can get it through the variable "SourcesDirectory"

Comment: I need to set the path relative to the base of the project in source control. this is because I also need to access some other directories.
I want to be able to set this when queuing a build. Can I set this with something like $(SourcesDir)\scripts\scriptname.ps1 when entering the build details in TFS?

Comment: Ok then you can use "SolutionRoot" variable.